# Import excel colls to sql

Tags: php, mysql, excel, csv

I'm looking to create a script to upload CSV files or xls and insert into the database. I've managed to make it until now, but I w

```
ID   CODE   CAP1   CAP2   CAP3
1    AA      50     60     70
2    BB      80     90     100
3    AA             120    130
```

What I would like to do is to insert it in a mysql table tbl_dimensions like this:

```
RECID   DRAFT_IMPORT   CODE   ID    HEADER    VALUE
1          XXXXX       AA      1     CAP1      50
2          XXXXX       AA      1     CAP2      60
3          XXXXX       AA      1     CAP3      70
4          XXXXX       BB      2     CAP1      80
5          XXXXX       BB      2     CAP2      90
6          XXXXX       BB      2     CAP3      100
7          XXXXX       AA      3     CAP1      NULL/0
8          XXXXX       AA      3     CAP2      120
9          XXXXX       AA      3     CAP3      130
```

Basically instead of creating a wide table in SQL in want to create a list in a table but I need to keep the item Code, AA, BB, etc. It's possible to have the same code multiple time so I want to use the row nr from CSV/XLS to coordinate the values from CAP1, CAP2, CAP3. Cap1,2 3, can be anything and changes every day so I cant define a table wide enough for each option that will occure.

Thank you very much

Comment: you tagged php , but no php code too show what you have done

Comment: Looks like a good datamodel for an Excel-User, but you should consider an additional table where you store `CODE` and `ID`, then you only need `ID` in `tbl_dimensions` and get `CODE` by joining on `ID`. Now you need to read each line of `CSV` and insert `ID` with the `HEADER` and `VALUE` for each `CAP`, when finished go to next line.

Comment: Hi Mike, thank you. I've managed to build an import script where I have all the columns, the problem is that you go from one customer to another and each of them have different table structures so I need to record them this way. it's a good sugestion yours as well but still don't know how to go to each header, and when finished go to next line. I'll rather have only one table with everything recorded.

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to figure out that will work with array. I still haven't sort it but I'll put my code here, maybe you can help me.

```
<?php
   function csv_to_array($filename='', $delimiter=',') {
    if(!file_exists($filename) || !is_readable($filename))      return
   FALSE;       $header = NULL;     $data = array();    if (($handle =
   fopen($filename, 'r')) !== FALSE)    {       while (($row =
   fgetcsv($handle, 1000, $delimiter)) !== FALSE)       {           if(!$header)
                $header = $row;
                        else
                $data[] = array_combine($header, $row);
                    }       fclose($handle);    }   return $data; } /**  * Example  */ print_r(csv_to_array('example.csv'));

   ?>
```

my csv file looks like this:

```
cod_piesa, lungime, latime, inaltime
gl, 5000,, 150
fd, 3000, 2000, 100
```

what I want to do is to insert into a mysql table like this

```
row = 0
cod_piesa = GL
header = lungime
value = 5000

next one

row = 0
cod_piesa = GL
header = latime
value = NULL

row = 0
cod_piesa = GL
header = inaltime
value = 150

row = 1
cod_piesa = FD..... and so on.
```

mysql table is called tbl_drafts and it has the columns draft_id, row, cod_piesa, header, value. draft_id is a temporary ID that I will generate let's say $draft_id=1

after insert I need to redirect him to a new page where I'll compare different results let's say 'verification.php'.

Thank you very much for all your answers

For time being I'm using a file that's uploaded on the server but I would need to have a manual upload option where visitor can upload the CSV or excel file.

I'm sure this will help a lot of people if solved.
I had a look into transposition option but I couldn't figure it out.

Comment: this is the output of print: Array ( [0] => Array ( [cod_piesa] => gl [ lungime] => 5000 [ latime] => [ inaltime] => 150 ) [1] => Array ( [cod_piesa] => fd [ lungime] => 3000 [ latime] => 2000 [ inaltime] => 100 ) )